# Raspberry as audio bridge

Tags: audio-playback, cars

I have a car with a 3.5mm jack for aux-in. It has also BT for my phone. In my phone, I have deezer (more or less like Spotify) that I use to send music to the car audio system.

It works fine, but since the plug is inside the glove box, I have to plug the phone every time and I guess that this will break the phone's jack one day.

Unfortunately, there is no "clean" way to bring the aux-in from the glove box to the gear shift where I'd like to have the phone and, anyway, it will not solve the plug in-out wearing problem.

Now the idea: since I cannot use the phone's BT to stream the music because I need it to connect to my car's freehand system to answer calls, I was thinking of using a Raspberry Pi as Wifi receiver of the stream from the Android phone.

Do I need something to stream audio from the phone to the Raspberry?  And what should I install on the Raspberry Pi to act as a wifi receiver audio streamer?

Another solution is to use a Raspberry to stream the music via the Linux player to something (another raspberry?) inside the glove box that can receive a BT or wifi stream and output it to the car's jack.

Basically, I just want to sit in the car, run the deezer app and listen to the music.

I hope I'm understandable and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Maybe that's worth I look: https://volumio.github.io/docs/index.html  https://volumio.org/get-started/. I did not try it yet.

Comment: Unless Deezer already supports it, you will have a hard time capturing its audio output and sending it to wifi, unfortunately. At very least this will require rooting the phone and even then I don't know if there's a ready-made app to do it.

Comment: Thank You for your comments. Volumio, regardless of my specific user case, looks interesting, I'll have a look.